# Wordpress Bulk fiels generation perf issue

Tags: wordpress, learndash

I'm using learndash and a plugin to generate certificates in bulk.
Right now i'm finding issues when generating these bulks ( performance issue )
what the plugin does is that it generates pdf files and then compress all of them into zip file
My question is : is there a way to optimise this workflow either through WHM or through wordpress
ps : GZIP is activated but i'm not sure if there's a certain configuration to make it work with jpg and zip files.